# Should I make up fajr (after missing it due to sleep) again if I'm not sure if I made it up before?

Tags: salat

When I woke up I noticed I didn’t pray fajr. I’m pretty sure I made it up after I woke up but I’m not 100 percent sure. A few hours later I was in a hurry and prayed my dhuhr and I left. The next day I am starting to doubt whether I made up my fajr or not. Should I disregard the doubt because I’m pretty sure that I made it up, or should I make it up again just in case? (I’m pretty sure I have whispers of shaytan if that helps you answer)

Answer (score 1):

### Salah/prayer must be prayed at the prescribed time :

[Surah-An-Nisa 4:103]

> After performing the ritual prayer, continue to remember God- standing,
> sitting, and lying on your sides- and once you are safe, keep up regular
> prayer, **for prayer is obligatory for the believers at prescribed times**.

Try to pray on time in that case you will be 100% sure that you prayed Salah/Prayer. If any case you missed Salah/Prayer then you can pray that immediately after remembering it.

### These may help you in remembering your prayed Salah/prayer:

- You can also download any Salah/Prayer tracker app, there are alot of apps which help you keep track of each salah/prayer
- You can make a schedule on a piece of paper for all obligatory prayer and after praying a salah/prayer, just mark it on the schedule

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are 100% sure you didn’t go with the most certain thought. It sounds dumb but maybe take a note of all salahs you pray so your mind is content

Answer (score 0):

First, any prayer you have missed could be done whenever you remember them as the prophet Mohammad PBUH have told us, and if you have doubts whether you have prayed or not, the best thing to do is to pray what you missed and cut the doubts completely.